# What is the preferred way to avoid SQL injections in Spark-SQL (on Hive)

Tags: scala, security, hive, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assume a SchemaRDD `rdd` with a registered table `customer`. You want to filter out records according to a user input. One idea you might have how to do this is the following:

```
rdd.sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name='$userInput'")
```

However, since the old days of PHP we know that this can lead to nasty things.
Is there an equivalent of PreparedStatement? The only thing I could find that looked remotely relevant is `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql`.

Comment: Wait... So.... SQL injection on Spark-SQL. And Spark-sql is a trial of implementing of some SQL-like functionality. NOT ALL. Again things like sql escape used to be a part of php and not SQL itself. Also... what's wrong with using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql`. Other than this - remember the "trial" and "some" part... Those escaped queries are not guaranteed to work with Spark-SQL.

Comment: Well, yes, it's a subset of SQL which doesn't mean it can't be exploited by injections which for instance enable the user to see data that he shouldn't have access to. If you look at the doc of escapeSql it seems to duplicate ' characters ( ' => '' ) which is not the way strings are escaped in spark-sql. Also I suppose there needs to be a canonical way to achieve that which is what I'm asking for.

Comment: What I am saying is... since the even the subset they are aiming for is not fully implemented, they are certainly not focusing on escaping. And hence, you will have to work on query-sanitation yourself.

Comment: See lit(value) in DataFrame API - I saw this [on the mail list today](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg43127.html); haven't tried it out.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the [thriftserver to expose jdbc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server), and then the usual techniques could be used (PreparedStatement etc.) to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
def safeSql(query,**args):
    spark.udf.register("arg", lambda x: args[x])
    return(spark.sql(query))
     
safeSql("select arg('a'),arg('b')",a=4,b="O'Malley").show()
```

The above is in pyspark but it can be done in Scala or other languages. The trick is to register an udf.

Answer (score 0):

See [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76830408/892621) for how to do this in pyspark 3.3.0+ using the built-in functionality.