# Escaping user inputs for Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have been using a JDBC connection to Spark's Thrift Server so far and using JDBC prepared statements to escape potentially malicious user input.

I am trying to port our code directly to HiveContext now (i.e. eliminate the use of Thrift Server) and I am not quite sure how to generate a properly escaped sql statement...

Wondering if someone has ideas on proper way to do this?

To be concrete, I would love to issue this statement

```
 val df = myHiveCtxt.sql(sqlText)
```

but I would like to defend against potential SQL injection.

Comment: See also comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669106/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-avoid-sql-injections-in-spark-sql-on-hive

Comment: Do you get the entirety of the query/statement from untrusted sources, or/versus, do you get parameter values from untrusted sources, and assemble the SQL query yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
args = {
  "a": "I'm",
  "b": 1964
}
spark.udf.register("arg", lambda x: args[x]) 
 
spark.sql("select arg('a'),arg('b')").show()
```

The trick is to register a UDF. The above snippet is python but it can be done in Scala and other languages.

The above is in pyspark but it can be done in Scala or other languages. The trick is to register an udf.